# Linear sum assignment -- faster algorithms for a structured cost matrix?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research, permutation-matrices

The Hungarian algorithm for the linear sum assignment problem with dimension $n$ has complexity $O(n^3)$. Can the complexity be improved if one is able to assume that the cost matrix is structured? I am particularly thinking of the case where the cost matrix is low-rank, or sparse, or banded.

Furthermore, it seems to me that if the cost matrix is a block matrix with $b$ equally-sized blocks, and off-diagonal blocks with elements equal to $+\infty$, then the problem decomposes into $b$ separate subproblems of size $n/b$, leading to complexity $O(b (n/b)^3) = O(n^3/b^2)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Normal use of the phrase "block diagonal" means off-diagonal elements are 0. Since this is the cost matrix, that implies free (zero cost) assignments. Unless you have a different meaning for "block diagonal", your decomposition idea is wrong.

Comment: @prubin -- Good point, thanks. I was thinking in terms of the maximum cost formulation. I've changed the question to keep it in terms of min-cost.

Comment: In that case I would agree with your complexity estimate.